# Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PopAsync: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I recently got that curious exception in my Xamarin App on iOS. I currently struggle to symbolicate it properly in HockeyApp but anyway here is the crash reporter log from HA:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         trucker_rolspedi [625]
Path:            /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B028371C-62B4-4BCD-8491-C78EFE825D22/trucker_rolspediOS.app/trucker_rolspediOS
Identifier:      com.rolsped.TruckerApp
Version:         1.1 (60)
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2016-12-04T04:53:09Z
Launch Time:     2016-12-04T04:46:07Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:  104-Xamarin

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x21efec5c
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException', reason: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Xamarin Exception Stack:
Parameter name: index
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource) <0x384df0 + 0x00040> in <15e850188d9f425bbeae90f0bbc51e17#ddbdd0f52c53581cb2d9c691bfe34183>:0 
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () <0x384b68 + 0x0001b> in <15e850188d9f425bbeae90f0bbc51e17#ddbdd0f52c53581cb2d9c691bfe34183>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) <0x24a68c + 0x0002f> in <15e850188d9f425bbeae90f0bbc51e17#ddbdd0f52c53581cb2d9c691bfe34183>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.Pop () <0x5678b4 + 0x00047> in <f9095492ed2b43559d0236ac22ab7223#ddbdd0f52c53581cb2d9c691bfe34183>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.OnPopAsync (System.Boolean animated) <0x567518 + 0x0005b> in <f9095492ed2b43559d0236ac22ab7223#ddbdd0f52c53581cb2d9c691bfe34183>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PopAsync (System.Boolean animated) <0x56708c + 0x0002f> in <f9095492ed2b43559d0236ac22ab7223#ddbdd0f52c53581cb2d9c691bfe34183>:0 
  at trucker_rolsped.Pages.Media.TaskPhotoUploadPage+<SendMediaOnClicked>d__9.MoveNext () <0xe86944 + 0x013bf> in <3fbc044b4d76429b8dee1ec91e769c22#ddbdd0f52c53581cb2d9c691bfe34183>:0
```

Here the Code from the root cause Stacktrace line. It must happen at the `await Navigation.PopAsync(animated: false)`statement:

```
       private async void SendMediaOnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMedia.IsEnabled = false;

            try
            {
                SelectedMedia.DokArt = _dokArt;
                SelectedMedia.TruckAppId = _truckAppId;

                UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Foto wird hochgeladen...");

                await AzureBlobStorageManager.Instance.UploadMediaAsync(SelectedMedia);

                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();

                switch (SelectedMedia.MediaState)
                {
                    case MediaState.Uploaded:

                        if (IsTakenPhoto)
                        {
                            var result = await DisplayAlert("Foto Upload", "Foto wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen. Möchten Sie das Foto jetzt vom Handy löschen?", "Ja", "Nein");

                            if (result)
                            {
                                //Platform specific file delete
                                var truckerappMedia = SelectedMedia.File.Path;

                                var platformFileHandler = DependencyService.Get<IFileHandling>();

                                if (platformFileHandler != null)
                                    if (await platformFileHandler.FileExistsAsync(truckerappMedia))
                                    {
                                        var deleted = await platformFileHandler.DeleteFileAsync(truckerappMedia);

                                        if (deleted)
                                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Foto wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen und am Handy gelöscht!!", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value: 2));

                                        else
                                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Foto konnte nicht gelöscht werden! Falls Sie das Foto nicht benötigen " +
                                                                               "bitte in der Fotogallery selbst löschen", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value: 5));

                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Upload erfolgreich!", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value: 2));


                        break;
                    case MediaState.Queued:
                        UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Upload erfolgt automatisch wenn Sie wieder mit Internet oder dem mobilem Netz verbunden sind!");
                        break;
                    case MediaState.Created:
                        await DisplayAlert("Media Info", "Upload MediaState.Created!", "Ok");
                        break;
                    case MediaState.Error:
                        await DisplayAlert("Media Info", "Upload MediaState.Error!", "Ok");
                        break;
                    default:
                        await DisplayAlert("Media Info", "Upload MediaState Unknown!", "Ok");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SelectedMedia.MediaState = MediaState.Error;
                await DisplayAlert("Sende Media Fehler", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (SelectedMedia.MediaState == MediaState.Uploaded)
                {
                    SelectedMedia?.Dispose();
                    SelectedMedia = null;
                }

                _workflowItem.TruckAuftragWorkFlow.TaskStatusId = 80;

                await Navigation.PopAsync(animated: false);
                _tcs.SetResult(true);
            }
        }
```

Here the 2 code areas where I instantiate and use the TakePhotoUploadPage:

**1. Usage: From another page called Task40ActionPage**

In **Task40ActionPage ** I invoke that method to show the TakePhotoUploadPage :

```
private async void RejectLoadInTimeClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _workflowItem.TruckAuftragLauf.FlagFotoLadezeit = null;

    try
    {
        await ShowPhotoPageAsync(this, _workflowItem);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance.SendExceptionToApplicationInsights(ex);
    }

    await Navigation.PopAsync(animated: false);
    _tcs.SetResult(true);
}

public async Task<bool> ShowPhotoPageAsync(Page page, WorkflowItem workflowItem)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    try
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TaskPhotoUploadPage(tcs, workflowItem, dokArt: "50"), animated: false);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tcs.SetException(e);
    }

    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

**2. Usage: From an ICommand  Action delegate:**

```
    public async Task Task50ActionAsync(WorkflowItem workflowItem)
    {
        bool isLastWorkItem = false;
        var page = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

        try
        {
            if (workflowItem.QuestionYn)
            {
                if (page != null)
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                        async () =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                bool isOk = await page.DisplayAlert("Todo Command", "Task50ActionAsync ausführen?", "Ja", "Nein");

                                if (isOk)
                                {
                                    await ShowPhotoPageAsync(page, workflowItem, dokArt: "60");

                                    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Aufgabe wird gespeichert...", MaskType.Black);
                                    isLastWorkItem = await InnerTask50ActionAsync(workflowItem);

                                    //PUSH changes to remote.db
                                    await OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.PushAsync(OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.TruckAuftragWorkFlowTable.TableName);

                                    if (isLastWorkItem)
                                    {
                                        // Set TAL to completed
                                        workflowItem.TruckAuftragLauf.IsCompleted = true;

                                        // Pop Workflow UI View
                                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await page.Navigation.PopAsync(animated: false));
                                    }
                                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance.SendExceptionToApplicationInsights(e);

                                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                                    async () =>
                                    {
                                        await
                                            page.DisplayAlert("Todo Command Error",
                                                $"TaskId={workflowItem.TaskId} Action Error:{e}", "Ok");
                                    });
                            }
                        });
            }
            else
            {
                await ShowPhotoPageAsync(page, workflowItem, dokArt: "60");

                UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Aufgabe wird gespeichert...", MaskType.Black);
                isLastWorkItem = await InnerTask50ActionAsync(workflowItem);

                //PUSH changes to remote.db
                await OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.PushAsync(OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.TruckAuftragWorkFlowTable.TableName);

                if (isLastWorkItem)
                {
                    // Set TAL to completed
                    workflowItem.TruckAuftragLauf.IsCompleted = true;

                    // Pop Workflow UI View
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await page.Navigation.PopAsync(animated: false));
                }
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance.SendExceptionToApplicationInsights(e);

            if (page != null)
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                    async () =>
                    {
                        await
                            page.DisplayAlert("Todo Command Error", $"TaskId={workflowItem.TaskId} Action Error:{e}",
                                "Ok");
                    });
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> ShowPhotoPageAsync(Page page, WorkflowItem workflowItem, string dokArt)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        try
        {
            await page.Navigation.PushAsync(new TaskPhotoUploadPage(tcs, workflowItem, dokArt: dokArt), animated: false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tcs.SetException(e);
        }

        return await tcs.Task;
    }
```

Thanks to everyone with helpful suggestions in advance,

Eric

Comment: Before you call Pop put breakpoint and check your Navigation stack. From exception it looks you Pop too many times and stack is empty

Comment:  I am absolutely sure you are right. The problem is that this case only happens very rarely. Most of the time it works.

Comment: Do you have the way to reproduce it constantly or it happens in unpredictable manner? Then it may be caused by double button clicks which you might want to protect against. Add code checking the stack before Pop and put break point there, so it will not be hit in normal case but only in problematic. I might find out more if you provide complete solution to debug. Because I cannot reproduce it without consuming your services.

Comment: It happens in an unpredictable manner. Sounds reasonable. Where / how can I send you the solution? I will try that suggestion with NavigationStack query.

Comment: you can share it on dropbox or github. Also please provide the way to reproduce it - at least most likely steps when it crashes. If I need credentials for the services you can email them to me yshteinm@hotmail.com

Comment: You need whole project or PCL project only? There are many secrets (api keys) that I can't provide. please send me your email contact at erich.brunner@rolsped.com and I will get back with download link and reproduction instructions. Thanks very much for your support!

Comment: my email is above in my comment. I would rather have complete sample solution so I don't have to spend time to recreate the rest

Comment: Also complete solution might help to find the problem if it is not in PCL but somewhere else

Comment: I just sent it to your email address for investigation

Answer (score 1):

As [Yuri S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250405/yuri-s). suggested that code works to fix a NavigationStack PopAsync when the Stack is empty:

```
                if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 1)
            {
                await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance.SendErrorToApplicationInsightsAsync($"Navigationstack Count == 1");
            }
            else
            {
                await Navigation.PopAsync(animated: false);
            }
```

Thanks for you great support!!!

Eric